# Blackberry Webworks: Cookies are not being saved on OS 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, blackberry-webworks

I'm trying to use cookies to pass data between two pages. I've used native javascript (document.cookie) and jquery (cookie plugin) to save them but still get the error.

No cookies are saved when testing on the real device. The values are never set so they are null.

They work on the simulator perfectly. The weird part is that if I load remote content (e.g.: a script from Google CDN) before saving the cookies, it works.

I haven't found anything on this issue yet.

- Device: Blackberry 9700 OS 5
- Blackberry Webworks SDK: 2.3.1.5
- Simulator: Blackberry 9700 / 8520 OS 5

UPDATE: This is the test code i'm using to save cookies.

```
<script>

    function getCookie(c_name)
    {
    if (document.cookie.length>0)
      {
      c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
      if (c_start!=-1)
        {
        c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1;
        c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
        if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
      }
    return "";
    }

    function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays)
    {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+
    ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    }        

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#next").click(function(){
            var opt = $("#options option:selected").val();
            setCookie("option",opt,100);                
            window.location.href = "two.html";
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the method outlined here ...

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Cookie-support-in-OS5/m-p/1448253#M18924

From blackberry forums.

Comment: I tried this and it's still not working on the device but it works in the simulator.